# What is the algorithm used for converting uuid::text in Postgresql?

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, uuid

A table in postgresql where one of columns is uuid as BYTEA is being exported to tsv.

For example uuid was: `625c3430-34d0-43eb-b85d-e3bd1d9f82e1` and exported value is: `b\\404\320C\353\270]\343\275\035\237\202\341`.

What is the algorithm behind converting uuid::text and for the reverse functionality also, from text to uuid.
I have to read this tsv, decode uuid from its text representation and "do additional stuff" depending on decoded uuid.

Are there some libraries for this in Java or do I need to write my own decoder for it?
If I have to write my own decoder any hints on algorithm for it are welcome.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-binary.html

Comment: FYI, Postgres efficiently stores the 128-bit [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) values in the [*UUID* data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html). For generating values, most folks use either the [*uuid-ossp*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) extension for a wide array of support of various [Versions of UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions), or the [*pgcrypto*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html) extension for random-based Version 4 only.

Comment: Is that `]` in the middle of your example value a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your initial uuid to byte array. Check every element of byte array and if the value is:

0 => "\000"

39 => "\047"

or '''' (single quote symbol)

92 => "\" or "\134" (backslash)

31 < value < 127 => character from value

any other is "\xxx" octal value.

And you have your "text representation" uuid.

To get uuid from "text representation" just go trough the steps in reverse.